# Ошибка TypeError: $drag[0] is undefined ... в jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, javascript

Ошибка гласит:

```
TypeError: $drag[0] is undefined
maxY = trackHeight - $drag[0].offsetHeight;
```

Никто не сталкивался случаем?

Инициализирую `jScrollPane` так:

```
$("#test").jScrollPane();
```

**upd** [ 1 ]

странно, все вроде норм., вот подключаю все нужные скрипты:

```
<!-- jScrollPane & MouseWheel http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jscrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jscrollpane/jquery.em.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jscrollpane/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<link   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jscrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.css" media="all" />
<!-- // END jScrollPane & MouseWheel -->
```

скрипты `jquery.em.js` и `mwheelIntent.js` опционально , так что если я их удалю или закомментирую, то ничего ни меняется.

В общем результат инициализации:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;" id="test">
lorem ipsum ... очень много lorem ipsum
<div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как видно появился `div` внизу, в котором еще один `div`, но ни в этом суть, смотрим картинку: [image: pic]

увы. Может к этому чуду еще картинки какие-нть надо подгружать или темы?

Comment: с `undefined`'ами любой скриптер сталкивался, но чуть больше кода не помешает

Comment: а нету другого кода. Все скрипты какие надо подключены, а весь мой код может уместиться в одну строку: `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#test").jScrollPane(); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот последняя версия скрипта](https://raw.github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js).

У вас, видимо, старый скрипт с некоторыми недочетами. Попробуйте этот и посмотрите на результат.

P.S. `$drag` давно нет в скрипте. У вас, видимо, скрипт еще за 2009 год.

UPD. [Вот страничка скрипта](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) возьмите остальные тоже отсюда. Все заработает ;)

Comment: А где взяли? Лучше тогда и все остальное скачать.

Comment: Подключив ваш скрипт ошибка пропала, jScrollPane якобы инициализируется, но сами скроллы не появляются вот в чем проблема, хотя появляются их контейнеры.

Comment: добавил ссылку на страницу плагина

Comment: см. upd[1].

Comment: Обверните текст в вашем блоке в какой-то элемент. Вместо 

<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;" id="test">
lorem ipsum ... очень много lorem ipsum
</div>

Сделайте


<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;" id="test">
<p>lorem ipsum ... очень много lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

Comment: Спасибо **iKuzko**, дей-но помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Все же написано:

```
$drag[0] is undefined
```

Массив может не объявлен...

Comment: Ну вот не объявлен, но я то тут при чем, я сделал как все в документации к нему сказано и фиг запускается.

Comment: это ошибка возникает в исходниках плагина, интересно

Comment: именно в исходниках.

Comment: там идут строчки 

    currentOffset = $drag.offset(false); // нормально
    currentOffset.top -= dragPosition;
    maxY = trackHeight - $drag[0].offsetHeight; // undefined

попробуйте вписать `console.log` где-нибудь перед вычислением `maxY` и посмотреть, что из себя представляет `$drag[0]`

Comment: Значит кривой jScrollPane, скачать новый с другого сайта

Comment: с оф.сайта брал, лог `undefined` показал.